# Viewing unicode strings in Intellij Idea debugger

Tags: debugging, unicode, intellij-idea

How to view Unicode encoded strings in Intellij Idea debugger data view?
e.g. consider following code

```
String str = "सुझाव"; //some Unicode string: utf-8
String str1 = "\u0938\u0941\u091d\u093e\u0935";
System.out.println(str);
```

Not able to view the variable- str - in data view of debugger, it shows garbage value.
Even though set value shows proper value.

[image]
Any suggestions/work-arounds?

Probably, missing some encoding setting somewhere.

Comment: Show us what you have tried before and what problem you are facing.

Comment: sorry, updated the question. not able to attach picture(don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 1):

Check project encoding. I have same issue. Idea shows variables content encoding in WIN-1252.
In version in `Editor > File Encodigs` you have: `IDE Encoding`, and `Project Encoding`. After changing `Project Encoding` to UTF-8 everything looks ok.

Comment: That may be a part of it, but I already had those set to UTF-8. Changing the debugger font (really that of the GUI) showed the emoji characters.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the **debugger font**.

Since you can view your unicode string in the code editor it means that everything is good with your symbols and encoding of the file.

**A font may not have glyphs for each unicode character**. That's the issue. You have different fonts for code editor and debugger. The debugger's font doesn't have glyphs for those symbols. Unfortunately, it turns out you can't change the font of the debugger.

I've just got resolved similar issue: [Why Intellij IDEA doesn't display  symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39289564/why-intellij-idea-doesnt-display-symbol)

Answer (score 1):

blank squares means those characteristics are not supported by your IDE font . change IDE font should solve it (**File** -> **Settings** -> **Appearance & Behavior** -> **Appearance**)

Comment: this [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207053315-Display-utf8-character-on-debugger-?page=1#community_comment_207424419) is helpful

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I copied your code and I can see your characters in my debugger.

Perhaps your file encoding is wrong - can you look in the lower right edge of your intellij window, does it say UTF-8 or something else?

Alternatively, if you use the operation *convert to Basic Latin* (position your cursor on the string and use alt-enter), does this work?

```
    String str = "\u0938\u0941\u091d\u093e\u0935"; //some Unicode string: utf-8
```

Comment: I can view UTF-8 strings fine in editor tab, but not in dubugger tab (as pointed in picture in question).