# Why Intellij IDEA doesn't display  symbol?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, unicode, encoding, symbols

Windows 8. Everything in the settings is set to **UTF-8**. Intellij IDEA displays Chinese characters, for example, which means it's really set to Unicode character set, but it displays a box instead of  (MATHEMATICAL_FRAKTUR_CAPITAL_G) symbol.

Debugger window:

[image: debugger window]

Comment: Perhaps the font you're using doesn't contain a glyph for that character?

Comment: I changed the font - it worked. Thanks! Although it still doesn't work in the debugger window, it's now displayed in the code editor, where it didn't work before. I'll just need to find how to change debugger's font. Could you please post it as an answer a bit explaining that font have glyps and they may not support all characters? I'll accept it.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth that's answer-worthy :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely that the particular font you're using doesn't contain a glyph for that character.  Try switching to another font.